# How to extract data from JSON response coming from external REST API using RestTemplate in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot application for consuming external API using RestTemplate.

Below is the service class that I have written to get response from external API:

```
public CustomOlapReports getReportListByClientId(String clientId) {
        ResponseEntity<CustomOlapReports> responseEntity = null;
        CustomOlapReports jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            final String uri = "https://chapi.cloudhealthtech.com/olap_reports/custom?client_api_id="+clientId;
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
            header.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer "+apiKey);
            header.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
            
            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("body",header);
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, CustomOlapReports.class);
            
            jsonResponse =  responseEntity.getBody();   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

The following is the response that I am getting using exchange() method:

```
{
    "responseMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "status": "OK",
    "statusCode": 1,
    "response": {
        "links": {
            "RCDSO - Production Environment Cost": {
                "href": "href 1"
            },
            "RCDSO - Development & UAT Environment Cost": {
                "href": "href 2"
            },
            "RCDSO - Total Cost for Prod - Compugen Managed": {
                "href": "href 3"
            },
            "RCDSO - Virtual Machine Cost": {
                "href": "href 4"
            },
            "RCDSO - Azure File Storage Cost": {
                "href": "href 5"
            },
            "RCDSO - Azure Backup and Site Recovery": {
                "href": "href 6"
            },
            "RCDSO - Azure App Services Cost": {
                "href": "href 7"
            }
        }
    }
}

/********************** CustomOlapReports.java *************************/

@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomOlapReports {
    
     @JsonProperty("links") 
     private Links links;
}
/********************** Links.java *************************/
@Setter
@Getter
public class Links {
    @JsonProperty("RCDSO - Production Environment Cost")
    private RCDSOProductionEnvironmentCost rCDSOProductionEnvironmentCost;
    
    @JsonProperty("RCDSO - Development & UAT Environment Cost")
    private RCDSODevelopmentUATEnvironmentCost rCDSODevelopmentUATEnvironmentCost;
    
    @JsonProperty("RCDSO - Total Cost for Prod - Compugen Managed")
    private RCDSOTotalCostForProdCompugenManaged rCDSOTotalCostForProdCompugenManaged;
    
    @JsonProperty("RCDSO - Virtual Machine Cost")
    private RCDSOVirtualMachineCost rCDSOVirtualMachineCost;
    
    @JsonProperty("RCDSO - Azure File Storage Cost")
    private RCDSOAzureFileStorageCost rCDSOAzureFileStorageCost;
    
    @JsonProperty("RCDSO - Azure Backup and Site Recovery")
    private RCDSOAzureBackupAndSiteRecovery rCDSOAzureBackupAndSiteRecovery;
    
    @JsonProperty("RCDSO - Azure App Services Cost")
    private RCDSOAzureAppServicesCost rCDSOAzureAppServicesCost;
}
/********************** RCDSOProductionEnvironmentCost.java *************************/
@Getter
@Setter
public class RCDSOProductionEnvironmentCost {
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;
}
/********************** RCDSODevelopmentUATEnvironmentCost.java *************************/
@Getter
@Setter
public class RCDSODevelopmentUATEnvironmentCost {
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;
}
/********************** RCDSOTotalCostForProdCompugenManaged.java *************************/
@Getter
@Setter
public class RCDSOTotalCostForProdCompugenManaged {
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;
}
/********************** RCDSOVirtualMachineCost.java *************************/
@Getter
@Setter
public class RCDSOVirtualMachineCost {
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;
}
/********************** RCDSOAzureFileStorageCost.java *************************/
@Getter
@Setter
public class RCDSOAzureFileStorageCost {
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;

}
/********************** RCDSOAzureBackupAndSiteRecovery.java *************************/
@Getter
@Setter
public class RCDSOAzureBackupAndSiteRecovery {
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;

}
/********************** RCDSOAzureAppServicesCost.java *************************/
@Getter
@Setter
public class RCDSOAzureAppServicesCost {
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private String href;

}
```

So now, before sending response to client side in my application. I want to fetch data from this response and want to do some manipulation and convert that into custom POJO class. I tried using JSONObject but got some exceptions.

I want to display this JSON data in HTML table using AJAX.

**So how should I extract or get individual data from above JSON?**

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JSON structure, let's assume you have the following POJOs:

```java
public class Report implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, Link> links;
    // getters, setters
}

public class Link {
    private String href;
    // getters, setters
}
```

Now instead of extracting the response body as a JSON `String`, convert it to POJO directly.

```java
public Report getReportListByClientId(String clientId) {
        
        ResponseEntity<Report> responseEntity = null;
        
        try {
            ..
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Report.class);
            
            return responseEntity.getBody();

        } catch (Exception e) {
           ..
        }
}
```

Assumption: the project has `Jackson` in classpath, so `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` will be enabled by default with `RestTemplate` for the above method to work.

Comment: This solution also did not worked for me.

Comment: Not working as in it doesn't get the expected output or throws an error? Could you share more details.

Comment: Not getting expected output.

Comment: I have updated my query with POJO classes that I've created as per JSON response coming from external API.

Comment: Can you update the question to show the result of `jsonResponse =  responseEntity.getBody()`?

Comment: I have just printed the value of responseEntity.getBody(). The value is com.example.apidemo.model.CustomOlapReports@50b89e83

Comment: Can you pls add `@ToString` from lombok to your POJOs and try again.

Comment: Okay, let me try.

Comment: 'CustomOlapReports(links=Links(rCDSOProductionEnvironmentCost=RCDSOProductionEnvironmentCost(\n'+
'href=https://chapi.cloudhealthtech.com/olap_reports/azure_cost/history.json?chart_type=bar&chart_x=time&chart_z=Service%20Categories&category_page=1\n'+
'&forecast_to_next=0&delta_type=none&chart_y[]=total_cost&interval=monthly&palette=Cloudhealth&dimensions[]=time&dimensions[]=Azure-Services&measures[]=total_cost&\n'+
'filters[]=Groupset-13125420057092:select:13125420068067&table_align_left=false&report_id=13125420056952),  and so on.

Comment: So the response is parsed correctly and stored in the POJO. You can access the values and use as you like, what's missing now? What else is expected.

Comment: Basically, I want to display href and the name (RCDSOProductionEnvironmentCost, RCDSOTotalCostForProdCompugenManaged etc) at client side inside table.

Comment: In that case, you can use the pojo structure as I've given. That will have a `Map<String, Link>` with the name as key and `link` object as value. You can further flatten it to extract href and return `Map<String, String>` to the client, which in json form will be something like `{ "RCDSO - Production Environment Cost" : "href 1" }` and can be displayed in the table.

Comment: Or you can even create another object as `class ReportResponse {  String name; String href; }`. Once you get the POJO (as defined in my answer) from restTemplate, manipulate it create `ReportResponse`, return the same to client as list of `ReportResponse` objects - `[ { "name": "RCDSO - Production Environment Cost", "href" : "href 1" }, ...]`. Name & Href being the two columns in your table on client side.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it using my code that I've mentioned in my question?

Comment: Why do you need a separate POJO (eg. RCDSOProductionEnvironmentCost.java) for each value, instead of just using a key-value structure like Map?

Comment: Okay let me try then. I am bit confused here. I'll let you know once done.

Comment: According to you, I just need two POJOs. 1. public class CustomOlapReports { private Map<String, Link> links; } and public class Links{ private String href; } Right?

Comment: Please help me with the rest. I need it to be done ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help u. You can use JsonPath to manipulate your string json.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

add this library to your code
and then try to use this

```
        String json = """
            {
                "links": {
                    "RCDSO - Production Environment Cost": {
                        "href": "href 1"
                    },
                    "RCDSO - Development & UAT Environment Cost": {
                        "href": "href 2"
                    },
                    "RCDSO - Total Cost for Prod - Compugen Managed": {
                        "href": "href 3"
                    },
                    "RCDSO - Virtual Machine Cost": {
                        "href": "href 4"
                    },
                    "RCDSO - Azure File Storage Cost": {
                        "href": "href 5"
                    },
                    "RCDSO - Azure Backup and Site Recovery": {
                        "href": "href 6"
                    },
                    "RCDSO - Azure App Services Cost": {
                        "href": "href 7"
                    }
                }
            }
            """;
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> links = JsonPath.read(json, "$.links");
    links.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println("k = " + key);
        System.out.print("v = ");
        value.forEach((key2, value2) -> {
            System.out.println("key = " + key2 + " : value = " + value2);
        });
    });
```

Comment: This solution did not worked for me. I am getting class not found exception. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayway.jsonpath.Predicate. I have added this dependency in pom.xml.
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @rsharma Did you sync the project after?

Comment: @G.Ciardini Yes, I did.